# capturing screenshot of image elements on a page using casperjs

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, dom, casperjs

i am working on a UI testing project. casperjs provides captureSelector method to capture only the particular element on the webpage. I have searched all over internet and cant find appropriate solution. The best so far I could gather is given code. Also I have to assume website doesnt have jquery script included already.

```
function getElementPath(element)
{
return "//" + $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tagName = this.nodeName;
    if ($this.siblings(tagName).length > 0) {
        tagName += "[" + $this.prevAll(tagName).length + "]";
    }
    return tagName;
}).get().join("/").toUpperCase();
}
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true});
casper.start("http://www.google.com/");
var images;

casper.then(function() {

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

images = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName("img");
});
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    this.captureSelector('img%D%.png'.replace('%D%',i),x(getElementPath(images[i])));
}
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no access to the DOM in casper context. You need to do this inside the page context with <kbd>[evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)</kbd>. The link also contains a good description why you can't do this.

The fix would be to generate the element path in the page, return the path into casper context and then capture the selector.

```js
function getElementPath(imgIndex) {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[imgIndex];
    return "//" + $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tagName = this.nodeName;
        if ($this.siblings(tagName).length > 0) {
            tagName += "[" + $this.prevAll(tagName).length + "]";
        }
        return tagName;
    }).get().join("/").toUpperCase();
}

var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true});
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start("http://www.google.com/");

casper.then(function() {
    var images = this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
    });
    var imagePath;
    for(var i = 0; i < images; i++){
        imagePath = this.evaluate(getElementPath, i);
        this.captureSelector('img%D%.png'.replace('%D%',i), x(imagePath));
    }
});

casper.run();
```

A possibly better approach would be to just download every image like this:

```js
var i = 0;
casper.on("resource.received", function(resource){
    // matches "image/png", "image/jpeg" ...
    if (resource.contentType.indexOf("image/") === 0) {
        this.download(resource.url, 'img%D%.png'.replace('%D%',i));
        i++;
    }
});
casper.start("http://www.google.com/").run();
```

This might not necessarily mean overhead because the images may be served from cache. This will download the images with the original resolution. The problem is that it will also download images that are defined in CSS, which may or may not be good, and it will fail when downloading inline images through data-URI.

Comment: this thing actually works..thanks... but there is an issue...
it captures all the image resources....it doesnt specifically take html DOM img elemnts and hence number of images is greater than what actually are present on the current page..

Comment: Yes, there is no way of knowing, where those were requested from (img element, CSS background-image or plain AJAX). This also doesn't work for data-URI.